# Jquery drop: function(event,ui) works when drop is triggered.But according to my requirement I need to traverse through list of items dropped

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Requirement is something like this.

List of Draggables:
Organisation
Amount Spent

List of Droppables:

After user drags and drops the necessary elements he clicks on a button which fetches the all the elements dropped one by one and sends it to a servlet.

I can get each element as ui.draggable.text() on drop event.But i need to traverse through dropped elements after all the required elements are dropped